# Excel VBA Rnd Not Actually Random

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that when i click a button, it "randomly" gives me a number in a msgbox:

```
dim number as double
number= Int(8 * Rnd + 1) - 1
MsgBox number
```

The thing is, the numbers aren't actually randomized. For example: If i start the macro, click the button twice, lets say i get the numbers 5 and 2. Now if i close the macro and open it again and click the button twice, i get the same two numbers 5 and 2.

Now i know that in VB.net there was a way to actually get it to spit out random numbers each time without repeating the "sequence" but it's been years since i touched vb.net so i don't quite remember, also i would not know how to use it in excel vba.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to initialize the random number function

```
Sub test()
Dim number As Double
Randomize
number = Int(8 * Rnd + 1) - 1
MsgBox number
End Sub
```

Comment: This is SOOOO unintuitive! Not, Rnd.Randomize(), or Rnd.Init()? No - an orphaned Randomize function! Blech! (Of course, it worked - thanks!)

Comment: I can't believe this is a thing... I spent the last 3 hours looking at every other part of my code because of course the random number generator was fine - upon testing, it generated new numbers... But every new workbook, same order...  Thank you for your help @ruedi!