# Round function VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I need simulate classic play cube (values 1-6) by Rnd function. My solution is `Round(5 * Rnd() + 1, 0)` , but when I generate 1 milion values, I have not good results (by picture).
[image: RESULTS HERE]
I think, that problem is in bad use of ROUND function, but I do not know where.
Thank you for your answers...

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. But this post seems to be a duplicate of [Is Excel VBA's Rnd() really this bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891165/is-excel-vbas-rnd-really-this-bad) (with an excellent answer). Yet, I can't be sure as I am failing to see a question in your post. Also, note that `Rnd()` must be initialized first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281011/excel-vba-rnd-not-actually-random

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at this piece-by-piece.

`Rnd()` gives a number between 0 and 1.

So `5 * Rnd() + 1` gives a number between 1 and 6.

We can think of this number as being equally likely to be in one of 10 half-integer areas: [1,1.5], [1.5,2]...[5.5,6].

One of these will round to 1 - [1,1.5].

Two of these will round to 2 - [1.5,2] and [2,2.5].

3, 4 and 5 similarly have two of these which will round to them.

One of these will round to 6 - [5.5,6]

This explains the distribution you're seeing.

Therefore `Round(6 * Rnd() + 0.5, 0)` should give you what you're looking for as it extends the area by half in both directions, so gives 1 and 6 the correct weightings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried randbetween() ?? worked fine for me...